# java.lang.NullPointerException android instrumentation tests Android Studio

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm following this codelab https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-compose-test-cupcake?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcourses%2Fpathways%2Fandroid-basics-compose-unit-4-pathway-2%23codelab-https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcodelabs%2Fbasic-android-kotlin-compose-test-cupcake#4

and after implementing a suite of tests, I'm getting `NullPointerException` on all 11 tests

app source code: https://github.com/google-developer-training/basic-android-kotlin-compose-training-cupcake/tree/navigation

test source code:

```kotlin
package com.example.cupcake.test

import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalContext
import androidx.compose.ui.test.junit4.createAndroidComposeRule
import androidx.compose.ui.test.onNodeWithContentDescription
import androidx.compose.ui.test.onNodeWithText
import androidx.compose.ui.test.performClick
import androidx.navigation.compose.ComposeNavigator
import androidx.navigation.testing.TestNavHostController
import com.example.cupcake.CupcakeApp
import com.example.cupcake.CupcakeScreen
import com.example.cupcake.R
import org.junit.Before
import org.junit.Rule
import org.junit.Test
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.Calendar
import java.util.Locale

@get:Rule
val composeTestRule = createAndroidComposeRule<ComponentActivity>()

private lateinit var navController: TestNavHostController

class CupcakeScreenNavigationTest {
    @Before
    fun setupCupcakeNavHost() {
        composeTestRule.setContent {
            navController = TestNavHostController(LocalContext.current).apply {
                navigatorProvider.addNavigator(ComposeNavigator())
            }
            CupcakeApp(navController = navController)
        }
    }

    private fun getFormattedDate(): String {
        val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1)
        val formatter = SimpleDateFormat("E MMM d", Locale.getDefault())
        return formatter.format(calendar.time)
    }

    private fun performNavigateUp() {
        val backText = composeTestRule.activity.getString(R.string.back_button)
        composeTestRule.onNodeWithContentDescription(backText).performClick()
    }

    private fun performCancelClick() {
        composeTestRule.onNodeWithStringId(R.string.cancel)
            .performClick()
    }

    private fun performNextClick() {
        composeTestRule.onNodeWithStringId(R.string.next)
            .performClick()
    }

    private fun navigateToFlavorScreen() {
        composeTestRule.onNodeWithStringId(R.string.one_cupcake)
            .performClick()
        composeTestRule.onNodeWithStringId(R.string.chocolate)
            .performClick()
    }

    private fun navigateToStartFromFlavorScreenByNavigatingUp() {
        navigateToFlavorScreen()
        performNavigateUp()
    }

    private fun navigateToStartFromFlavorScreenByCancelling() {
        navigateToFlavorScreen()
        performCancelClick()
    }

    private fun navigateToPickupScreen() {
        navigateToFlavorScreen()
        performNextClick()
    }

    private fun navigateToFlavorScreenByNavigationUp() {
        navigateToPickupScreen()
        performNavigateUp()
    }

    private fun navigateToStartFromPickupScreenByCancelling() {
        navigateToPickupScreen()
        performCancelClick()
    }

    private fun navigateToSummaryScreen() {
        navigateToPickupScreen()
        composeTestRule.onNodeWithText(getFormattedDate())
            .performClick()
        performNextClick()
    }

    private fun navigateToPickupScreenByNavigationUp() {
        navigateToSummaryScreen()
        performNavigateUp()
    }

    private fun navigateToStartFromSummaryScreenByCancelling() {
        navigateToSummaryScreen()
        performCancelClick()
    }

    @Test
    fun cupcakeNavHost_verifyStartDestination() {
        navController.assertCurrentRouteName(CupcakeScreen.Start.name)
    }

    @Test
    fun cupcakeNavHost_verifyBackNavigationNotShownOnStartOrderScreen() {
        val backText = composeTestRule.activity.getString(R.string.back_button)
        composeTestRule.onNodeWithContentDescription(backText).assertDoesNotExist()
    }

    @Test
    fun cupcakeNavHost_clickOneCupcake_navigatesToSelectFlavorScreen() {
        navigateToFlavorScreen()
        performNextClick()
        navController.assertCurrentRouteName(CupcakeScreen.Flavor.name)
    }

    @Test
    fun cupcakeNavHost_clickUpButtonFromFlavorScreen_navigatesToStartScreen() {
        navigateToStartFromFlavorScreenByNavigatingUp()
        navController.assertCurrentRouteName(CupcakeScreen.Start.name)
    }

    @Test
    fun cupcakeNavHost_clickCancelButtonFromFlavorScreen_navigatesToStartScreen() {
        navigateToStartFromFlavorScreenByCancelling()
        navController.assertCurrentRouteName(CupcakeScreen.Start.name)
    }

    @Test
    fun cupcakeNavHost_navigateToPickupScreen() {
        navigateToPickupScreen()
        navController.assertCurrentRouteName(CupcakeScreen.Pickup.name)
    }

    @Test
    fun cupcakeNavHost_clickUpButtonFromPickupScreen_navigatesToFlavorScreen() {
        navigateToFlavorScreenByNavigationUp()
        navController.assertCurrentRouteName(CupcakeScreen.Flavor.name)
    }

    @Test
    fun cupcakeNavHost_clickCancelButtonFromPickupScreen_navigatesToStartScreen() {
        navigateToStartFromPickupScreenByCancelling()
        navController.assertCurrentRouteName(CupcakeScreen.Start.name)
    }

    @Test
    fun cupcakeNavHost_navigateToSummaryScreen() {
        navigateToSummaryScreen()
        navController.assertCurrentRouteName(CupcakeScreen.Summary.name)
    }

    @Test
    fun cupcakeNavHost_clickUpButtonFromSummaryScreen_navigatesToPickupScreen() {
        navigateToPickupScreenByNavigationUp()
        navController.assertCurrentRouteName(CupcakeScreen.Pickup.name)
    }

    @Test
    fun cupcakeNavHost_clickCancelButtonFromSummaryScreen_navigatesToStartScreen() {
        navigateToStartFromSummaryScreenByCancelling()
        navController.assertCurrentRouteName(CupcakeScreen.Start.name)
    }
}
```

sample error:

```
01-15 13:38:34.227 14838 14860 I TestRunner: started: cupcakeNavHost_clickCancelButtonFromFlavorScreen_navigatesToStartScreen(com.example.cupcake.test.CupcakeScreenNavigationTest)
01-15 13:38:34.261 14838 14860 E TestRunner: failed: cupcakeNavHost_clickCancelButtonFromFlavorScreen_navigatesToStartScreen(com.example.cupcake.test.CupcakeScreenNavigationTest)
01-15 13:38:34.261 14838 14860 E TestRunner: ----- begin exception -----
01-15 13:38:34.262 14838 14860 E TestRunner: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-15 13:38:34.262 14838 14860 E TestRunner:    at androidx.test.internal.util.Checks.checkNotNull(Checks.java:38)
01-15 13:38:34.262 14838 14860 E TestRunner:    at androidx.test.ext.junit.rules.ActivityScenarioRule.getScenario(ActivityScenarioRule.java:125)
01-15 13:38:34.262 14838 14860 E TestRunner:    at androidx.compose.ui.test.junit4.AndroidComposeTestRule_androidKt.getActivityFromTestRule(AndroidComposeTestRule.android.kt:345)
01-15 13:38:34.262 14838 14860 E TestRunner:    at androidx.compose.ui.test.junit4.AndroidComposeTestRule_androidKt.access$getActivityFromTestRule(AndroidComposeTestRule.android.kt:1)
01-15 13:38:34.262 14838 14860 E TestRunner:    at androidx.compose.ui.test.junit4.AndroidComposeTestRule_androidKt$createAndroidComposeRule$1.invoke(AndroidComposeTestRule.android.kt:116)
01-15 13:38:34.262 14838 14860 E TestRunner:    at androidx.compose.ui.test.junit4.AndroidComposeTestRule_androidKt$createAndroidComposeRule$1.invoke(AndroidComposeTestRule.android.kt:116)
01-15 13:38:34.262 14838 14860 E TestRunner:    at androidx.compose.ui.test.junit4.AndroidComposeTestRule$special$$inlined$AndroidComposeUiTestEnvironment$1.getActivity(ComposeUiTest.android.kt:587)
01-15 13:38:34.262 14838 14860 E TestRunner:    at androidx.compose.ui.test.AndroidComposeUiTestEnvironment$AndroidComposeUiTestImpl.getActivity(ComposeUiTest.android.kt:406)
01-15 13:38:34.262 14838 14860 E TestRunner:    at androidx.compose.ui.test.AndroidComposeUiTestEnvironment$AndroidComposeUiTestImpl.setContent(ComposeUiTest.android.kt:483)
01-15 13:38:34.262 14838 14860 E TestRunner:    at androidx.compose.ui.test.junit4.AndroidComposeTestRule.setContent(AndroidComposeTestRule.android.kt:340)
01-15 13:38:34.262 14838 14860 E TestRunner:    at com.example.cupcake.test.CupcakeScreenNavigationTest.setupCupcakeNavHost(CupcakeScreenNavigationTest.kt:29)
01-15 13:38:34.262 14838 14860 E TestRunner:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-15 13:38:34.262 14838 14860 E TestRunner:    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
01-15 13:38:34.262 14838 14860 E TestRunner:    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
01-15 13:38:34.262 14838 14860 E TestRunner:    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
01-15 13:38:34.262 14838 14860 E TestRunner:    at androidx.test.internal.runner.junit4.statement.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:76)
01-15 13:38:34.262 14838 14860 E TestRunner:    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
01-15 13:38:34.262 14838 14860 E TestRunner:    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
01-15 13:38:34.262 14838 14860 E TestRunner:    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
01-15 13:38:34.262 14838 14860 E TestRunner:    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
01-15 13:38:34.262 14838 14860 E TestRunner:    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
01-15 13:38:34.262 14838 14860 E TestRunner:    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
01-15 13:38:34.262 14838 14860 E TestRunner:    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
01-15 13:38:34.262 14838 14860 E TestRunner:    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
01-15 13:38:34.262 14838 14860 E TestRunner:    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
01-15 13:38:34.262 14838 14860 E TestRunner:    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
01-15 13:38:34.262 14838 14860 E TestRunner:    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
01-15 13:38:34.262 14838 14860 E TestRunner:    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
01-15 13:38:34.262 14838 14860 E TestRunner:    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
01-15 13:38:34.262 14838 14860 E TestRunner:    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
01-15 13:38:34.262 14838 14860 E TestRunner:    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
01-15 13:38:34.262 14838 14860 E TestRunner:    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
01-15 13:38:34.262 14838 14860 E TestRunner:    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
01-15 13:38:34.262 14838 14860 E TestRunner:    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
01-15 13:38:34.262 14838 14860 E TestRunner:    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
01-15 13:38:34.262 14838 14860 E TestRunner:    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
01-15 13:38:34.262 14838 14860 E TestRunner:    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
01-15 13:38:34.262 14838 14860 E TestRunner:    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
01-15 13:38:34.262 14838 14860 E TestRunner:    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
01-15 13:38:34.262 14838 14860 E TestRunner:    at androidx.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:67)
01-15 13:38:34.262 14838 14860 E TestRunner:    at androidx.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:58)
01-15 13:38:34.262 14838 14860 E TestRunner:    at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:446)
01-15 13:38:34.262 14838 14860 E TestRunner:    at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2205)
01-15 13:38:34.262 14838 14860 E TestRunner: ----- end exception -----
01-15 13:38:34.263 14838 14860 I TestRunner: finished: cupcakeNavHost_clickCancelButtonFromFlavorScreen_navigatesToStartScreen(com.example.cupcake.test.CupcakeScreenNavigationTest)

java.lang.NullPointerException
at androidx.test.internal.util.Checks.checkNotNull(Checks.java:38)
at androidx.test.ext.junit.rules.ActivityScenarioRule.getScenario(ActivityScenarioRule.java:125)
at androidx.compose.ui.test.junit4.AndroidComposeTestRule_androidKt.getActivityFromTestRule(AndroidComposeTestRule.android.kt:345)
at androidx.compose.ui.test.junit4.AndroidComposeTestRule_androidKt.access$getActivityFromTestRule(AndroidComposeTestRule.android.kt:1)
at androidx.compose.ui.test.junit4.AndroidComposeTestRule_androidKt$createAndroidComposeRule$1.invoke(AndroidComposeTestRule.android.kt:116)
at androidx.compose.ui.test.junit4.AndroidComposeTestRule_androidKt$createAndroidComposeRule$1.invoke(AndroidComposeTestRule.android.kt:116)
at androidx.compose.ui.test.junit4.AndroidComposeTestRule$special$$inlined$AndroidComposeUiTestEnvironment$1.getActivity(ComposeUiTest.android.kt:587)
at androidx.compose.ui.test.AndroidComposeUiTestEnvironment$AndroidComposeUiTestImpl.getActivity(ComposeUiTest.android.kt:406)
at androidx.compose.ui.test.AndroidComposeUiTestEnvironment$AndroidComposeUiTestImpl.setContent(ComposeUiTest.android.kt:483)
at androidx.compose.ui.test.junit4.AndroidComposeTestRule.setContent(AndroidComposeTestRule.android.kt:340)
at com.example.cupcake.test.CupcakeScreenNavigationTest.setupCupcakeNavHost(CupcakeScreenNavigationTest.kt:29)
```

I'm failing to understand why a null pointer would take place; comparing with the code in the codelab it seems my implementation should be fine

I tried replacing function calls with manual invocations and I get the same result

for example, with `cupcakeNavHost_clickCancelButtonFromFlavorScreen_navigatesToStartScreen`

```
--- foo1    2024-01-15 13:41:47.399073540 +0000
+++ foo2    2024-01-15 13:42:09.080486524 +0000
@@ -1,5 +1,7 @@
     @Test
     fun cupcakeNavHost_clickCancelButtonFromFlavorScreen_navigatesToStartScreen() {
-        navigateToStartFromFlavorScreenByCancelling()
+        navigateToFlavorScreen()
+        composeTestRule.onNodeWithStringId(R.string.cancel)
+            .performClick()
         navController.assertCurrentRouteName(CupcakeScreen.Start.name)
     }
```

any hints to put me on the right track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to move

```kotlin
@get:Rule
val composeTestRule = createAndroidComposeRule<ComponentActivity>()

private lateinit var navController: TestNavHostController
```

into the `CupcakeScreenNavigationTest` class:

```kotlin
class CupcakeScreenNavigationTest {
    @get:Rule
    val composeTestRule = createAndroidComposeRule<ComponentActivity>()

    private lateinit var navController: TestNavHostController

    @Before
    fun setupCupcakeNavHost() {
        composeTestRule.setContent {
            navController = TestNavHostController(LocalContext.current).apply {
                navigatorProvider.addNavigator(ComposeNavigator())
            }
            CupcakeApp(navController = navController)
        }
    }

[...]
```